# How to build a JSON array from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, json

Okay I have been racking my brain trying to build a JSON array from mysql. The array MUST be in the following format. I am using fullcalendar and want to make the events on the calendar dynamic. Below is the code that builds the array, but currently it does not get the information from mysql

```
$year = date('Y');
$month = date('m');

echo json_encode(array(

    //Each array below must be pulled from database
        //1st record
        array(
        'id' => 111,
        'title' => "Event1",
        'start' => "$year-$month-10",
        'url' => "http://yahoo.com/"
    ),

         //2nd record
         array(
        'id' => 222,
        'title' => "Event2",
        'start' => "$year-$month-20",
        'end' => "$year-$month-22",
        'url' => "http://yahoo.com/"
    )

));
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Is something like this what you want to do?

```
$return_arr = array();

$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table"); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['id'] = $row['id'];
    $row_array['col1'] = $row['col1'];
    $row_array['col2'] = $row['col2'];

    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

It returns a json string in this format:

```
[{"id":"1","col1":"col1_value","col2":"col2_value"},{"id":"2","col1":"col1_value","col2":"col2_value"}]
```

OR something like this:

```
$year = date('Y');
$month = date('m');

$json_array = array(

//Each array below must be pulled from database
    //1st record
    array(
    'id' => 111,
    'title' => "Event1",
    'start' => "$year-$month-10",
    'url' => "http://yahoo.com/"
),

     //2nd record
     array(
    'id' => 222,
    'title' => "Event2",
    'start' => "$year-$month-20",
    'end' => "$year-$month-22",
    'url' => "http://yahoo.com/"
)

);

echo json_encode($json_array);
```

Comment: +1 beat me to it.  If all the DB columns are the right names, you should be able to drop the assignment and just push $row to the array.

Comment: Why are you creating `$row_array`? Why not `SELECT id, title, '$year-month-10' as start,url FROM table`, and do a direct `$return_arr[] = $row;`?

Comment: @Kevin, Yes, you are correct. I actually quickly pulled this from an autocomplete example where I had to assign the array values different names. So +1 right back at you!

Comment: Yeah, one doesn't get an alert of another comment pending while writing one :)

Comment: I am still not getting it. The array must show exactly as above otherwise the information does not show up on the calendar.

Comment: Could you push each indivdual array into another and then json_encode? Like this line does: `array_push($return_arr,$row_array);`

Comment: Do mean the field names when you say 'exactly as above'?

Comment: I am using a script called fullcalendar. The code mus allow me to echo out exactly like this

Comment: array('id' => 111,         'title' => "Event1",         'start' => "$year-$month-10",         'url' => "http://yahoo.com/"     ),

Comment: OK. You should be able to push each of those into another array with array_push the json_echo. That's what the while loop is doing with the db rows.

Comment: Could you please provide me an example using the code that I posted above? Sorry I have been using PHP for some time now but am new to JSON

Comment: Using the code you posted I am getting an error rning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Comment: I updated my answer with another example. Double check you sql statement to troubleshoot the error.

Comment: Okay I guess I will keep trying on my own. The c ode you posted is exactly what I need but I have to loop through the database to get each record like above. The page tha has the code is called from the calendar script to display each event on the calendar. So I guess I am not understanding your code. So I am sure that with trial and error I will be able to eventually get the script to work with a database. Thanks anyway

Comment: I managed to get the code to work by deleting $json_array = array( ) call that was wrapped around the code. Thanks

Comment: Excellent just what i was looking for

Answer (score 11):

The PDO solution, just for a better implementation then `mysql_*`:

```
$array = $pdo->query("SELECT id, title, '$year-month-10' as start,url 
  FROM table")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($array);
```

Nice feature is also that it will leave integers as integers as opposed to strings.

Comment: `PDO` is _the_ defacto standard to connect to various databases in PHP nowadays, one of which is `MySQL`. Still using the mysql-extension in IMHO about as bad as still making hew `HTML 3.2` pages. If your project _really_ asks for it, go ahead, but new code should have nothing do with it, and if not `PDO`, at least use `mysqli` (note: the '`i`' stands for _improved_ ).

Comment: I have to use mysql as the others are not available to me.

Comment: I have been playing around with PDO. Thanks for the push to actually update some of my code. Already have it in place and running on some older code. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Just an update for Mysqli users :

```
$base= mysqli_connect($dbhost,  $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbbase);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

$return_arr = array();

if ($result = mysqli_query( $base, $sql )){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $row_array['id'] = $row['id'];
    $row_array['col1'] = $row['col1'];
    $row_array['col2'] = $row['col2'];

    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
   }
 }

mysqli_close($base);

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

Comment: I tried both the pdo and the sqli and I cant get the array to log properly.  You are using `echo json_encode($array);` which doesnt work for me but `Echo $json->encode($arr);` does work for me...why?  I use `mysql_query` and create a `mysql_fetch_object`.

Answer (score 1):

**Use this**

```
$array = array();
$subArray=array();
$sql_results = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `location`');

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_results))
{
    $subArray[location_id]=$row['location'];  //location_id is key and $row['location'] is value which come fron database.
    $subArray[x]=$row['x'];
    $subArray[y]=$row['y'];


 $array[] =  $subArray ;
}
echo'{"ProductsData":'.json_encode($array).'}';
```