# how to pass the $ _POST array through $ _SESSION to $ _GET?

Tags: php, session

I need to solve this problem. I have two files, one for the transmission of data to the database

**
**

```
<?php
// setup the database connect
//http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['display_name'])) {
    $_SESSION['display_name'] = $_POST['display_name'];
    echo $_SESSION['display_name'] ;
}
$link = mysql_connect('xxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxx', 'xxxxxx');
if (!$link)
    exit;
mysql_select_db('xxxxxxxx',$link);
if($_POST['attraction_id'] && $_POST['display_name']){
    echo $_POST['attraction_id'] . "   " . $_POST['display_name'];
}
if($_POST['restaurant_id'] && $_POST['display_name']){
    echo $_POST['restaurant_id'] . "   " . $_POST['display_name'];
}
if($_POST['Guest']){
    mysql_close();
}


//$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO user_favorite(user_id_name,user_favorite_photo,user_favorite_work_time,user_favorite_type,user_favorite_ticket_price) VALUES ('%s')",$_POST['restaurant_id']);
if($_POST['restaurant_id']){
    $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO user_favorite(restaurant_id,display_name) VALUES ('%d','%s')",$_POST['restaurant_id'],$_POST['display_name']);
}
if($_POST['attraction_id']){
    $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO user_favorite(attraction_id,display_name) VALUES ('%d','%s')",$_POST['attraction_id'],$_POST['display_name']);
}

if(!$sql){
    echo mysql_error($link);
}

// lets run our query
$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);

if($result){
    echo "INSERT";
}
else{
    echo "NOT INSERT";
}
```

The other file is used to return the data to the database in json format

**get.php**

```
<?php
//http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php
$link = mysql_connect('mysql.hostinger.com.ua', 'xxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxx');

mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link);
$db  =  mysql_select_db('xxxxxxxxxxx');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281963/how-to-build-a-json-array-from-mysql-database
$return_arr = array();
session_start();
$sql = sprintf("SELECT *
FROM restaurant AS r, user_favorite AS uf, user AS u
WHERE uf.restaurant_id = r.restaurant_id
AND uf.display_name = u.display_name
AND uf.display_name ='%s'",$_SESSION['display_name']);
$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['restaurant_id'] = $row['restaurant_id'];
    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}
echo json_encode($return_arr);
mysql_close($link);
```

How  I  transfer data through the `$ _POST` (ex `$_POST['display_name']`) array to aray `$ _SESSION` and from `$_SESSION` array  to the array `$ _GET` or another?

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: `$_SESSION['x'] == $_POST['x'];` so the session variable X will have the value of the posted field with name X

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: no no i need transfer data  session array from post.php  to get.php in my sql query code<br/>
`code $return_arr = array();
session_start();
$sql = sprintf("SELECT *
FROM restaurant AS r, user_favorite AS uf, user AS u
WHERE uf.restaurant_id = r.restaurant_id
AND uf.display_name = u.display_name
AND uf.display_name ='%s'",$_SESSION['display_name']);` How correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['display_name'] = $_POST['display_name'];
```

then later on

```
<a href="foo.php?display_name=<?php echo $_SESSION['display_name'] ?>">bar</a>
```

Comment: no no i need transfer data for post in post.php to get.php in my sql query code<br/>
`code $return_arr = array();
session_start();
$sql = sprintf("SELECT *
FROM restaurant AS r, user_favorite AS uf, user AS u
WHERE uf.restaurant_id = r.restaurant_id
AND uf.display_name = u.display_name
AND uf.display_name ='%s'",$_SESSION['display_name']);`

Comment: session_start();

$_SESSION['display_name'] = $_POST['display_name']; this is right answer!thank you!