# ajax variable cannot able to pass inside push in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to pass ajax variable inp instead of i in date(y,m,i). If i pass this variable inp instead of i means it gives me a blank page. How to solve this problem.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();
$.ajax({
    url : 'cal_db.php',
success:function(result)
{
   var out = eval("("+ result +")");
   var inp = out[0].id; 
}
});
var arr = [];
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
editable: true,
events: function(){
for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
  arr.push({
    title: 'All Day Event',
    start: new Date(y,m,i)
  });
}
return arr;
}()
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `eval()`. Set the correct mime type on the server and/or specify the datatype as json in the ajax call.

In the very beginning of **cal_db.php**:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

This would make the `dataType` below redudant.

If you want to make use of the ajax response in the datepicker, you need to move the datepicker code inside the `success` callback.

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'cal_db.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function(result) {
       var inp = result[0] ? result[0].id : null;

       if(inp){
           $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ /* make use of inp */ });
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank You this worked perfectly. Is their any possibilities to get how many row return in json from database.

Comment: @Serma No problem. There are a lot of threads answering that. Here is one for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281963/how-to-build-a-json-array-from-mysql-database

Answer (score -1):

Just declare the inp variable outside the success function, i guess this should help you, and even u can parse it in Integer format and the use.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();
var inp = -1;
$.ajax({
      url : 'cal_db.php',
      success:function(result)
      {
          var out = eval("("+ result +")");
          inp  = out[0].id; 
      }
});
var arr = [];
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     editable: true,
     events: function(){
     for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
     arr.push({
     title: 'All Day Event',
     start: new Date(y,m,inp)
});
}
```

Comment: It's an asyncronous call. He will never be able to make use of the value being set in the callback.