# Complicated SQL select

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, join

I have table `requests`

```
+------+----------+
| id   | distance |
+------+----------+
|    1 | 1.5km    |
|    2 | 1.3km    |
+------+----------+
```

and table `points` related to `requests`

```
+------+------------+--------------------+-------+
| id   | request_id | address            | order |
+------+------------+--------------------+-------+
|    1 |          1 | some_addrs         |     1 |
|    2 |          1 | second_addrs       |     2 |
|    3 |          2 | for_id_2_adddrs    |     2 |
|    4 |          2 | for_id_2_sec_addrs |     2 |
+------+------------+--------------------+-------+
```

table points can contain several rows which are related to **ONE** request and contain its own point position address. For example request can have departure, destination and its middle "pass through" points (locations)
My problem is: I want to make as simple as possible **SQL** to select *REQUEST* with all of its locations, which are in the table `points`
Please, I don't need exactly this strategy of storing information, help me if someone knows how to do this.

**I wll give more info. There is a service for taxi. For example, client ordered to go from point A to point D through point B and through point C. i have to save all points which user has put in order form. i have table for orders and i have table for points that contains all Geo Location data, and any row in POINT table can correspont to ONE order. I mean that one order can contain 2 and more points. My question is how to get all orders with all its points in array or json or any type of data**

each request can have infinite point rows, but those rows contain request_id. so, one request can contain for example 10 points and i want to get them all by selecting all requests. finally i want to get this data: json example:

```
`{
  ['id': 1, 'distance': 1, 
     [{'address': 'some address'}, 
      {'address: 'second address'}, 
      {'address': 'third address and etc'}],
   'id': 2, 'distance': 4.1,
     [{'address': 'some address'},
      {'address: 'second address'},
      {'address': 'third address and etc'}]
  ]
 }`
```

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? In tabular format it would be a simple JOIN between the two tables. It shouldn't be so easy, so I suspect you're leaving something out. (Or alternately: *what is it that you're trying to do using the two tables?*)

Comment: [***Have you tried anything?***](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Post any attempted solutions and desired output

Comment: [How to build a JSON array from MySQL database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281963/how-to-build-a-json-array-from-mysql-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relate the tables using `JOIN`:

```sql
select r.id as request_id, r.distance
     , p.id as point_id, r.address
from requests as r
     inner join ponts as p on r.id = p.request_id
order by r.id, p.id;
```

The above query will give you all the data from `requests` and `points`, ordered by request id and point id.

Comment: I wll give more info. There is a service for taxi. For example, client ordered to go from point A to point D though point B and through point C. i have to save all points which user has put in order form. i have table for orders and i have table for points that contains all Geo Location data, and any row in POINT table can correspont to ONE order. I mean that one order can contain 2 and more points. My question is how to get  all orders with all its points in array or json or any type of data.

Comment: @CJSuspend edit your question and include additional info (don't post this kind of updates in comments). Include your desired output and any attempted solutions (if any)

Comment: @CJSuspend let me see if I understand... each `request` has *two* `point` rows and you want to get some kind of result that has those two points in a single row?

Comment: each request can have infinite point rows, but those rows contain request_id. so, one request can contain for example 10 points and i want to get them all by selecting all requests. 
finally i want to get this data:

json example: {['id': 1, 'distance': 1, [{'address': 'some address'}, {'address: 'second address'}, {'address': 'third address and etc'}] }