# SQL database to Json array

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, json

Hello I recently created a database using this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/a-basic-mysql-tutorial

I need to convert my sql database to a json array (like the one shown below) I am making my first mobile app using phone gap, this question isn't about phone gap but i doubt providing some context can't hurt.

I want the app (which can only use html, css and js)  to make requests to a sql database the best way to do this for me is to convert the whole database to a json array once a phone makes one request for the json the new json database will be cached on the phone for that day.

(even if caching like this isn't possible or practical it doesn't matter in regards to this question)

I have added three "listings" to the database with via the following method:

```
INSERT INTO anime 
(id
,category
,genre
,title
,description 
,image_link
,date_added
) VALUES 
(NULL
,"Mainstream"
,"Action"
,"the title"
,"the name"
,"200 word description"
,"imagename.png"
,'2012-04-14'
);
```

I am unsure whether this method has created the database the way I wanted, as I have tried making multiple requests for the full information and only one way has worked that being said my PHP skills are rubbish.

[image]

I was hoping to generate something along the lines of this (any better ways to format it would be greatly appreciated and how to grab and use information from it easily ) i have been looking at `json_encode();` and have read: [How to build a JSON array from mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281963/how-to-build-a-json-array-from-mysql-database) and other stacks..

```
categories: [
        {
        "category-name" : "Mainstream",
        "category-description" : "Everyones watching them for a reason",
        "category-link" : "#mainstream",
        "Mainstream" : [
            {
                "genres" : [
                    {
                        "genre-name" : "Action",
                        "genre-description" : "Mainstream: Fight them off",
                        "list" : [
                            {
                                "img" : "www.ActionimglinkMainstream1.com",
                                "name" : "ActionMainstreamname1",
                                "description" : "this Action is Mainstream name 1"
                            },
                            {
                                "img" : "www.ActionimglinkMainstream2.com",
                                "name" : "ActionNewname2",
                                "description" : "this Action is Mainstream name 2"
                            },
                            {
                                "img" : "www.FantasyimglinkMainstream3.com",
                                "name" : "FantasyMainstreamname3",
                                "description" : "this Action is Mainstream name 3"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "genre-name" : "Fantasy",
                        "genre-description" : "Mainstream: I put a spell on you",
                        "list" : [
                            {
                                "img" : "www.FantasyimglinkMainstream1.com",
                                "name" : "FantasyMainstreamname1",
                                "description" : "this Fantasy is Mainstream name 1"
                            },
                            {
                                "img" : "www.ActionimglinkMainstream2.com",
                                "name" : "FantasyNewname2",
                                "description" : "this Fantasy is Mainstream name 2"
                            },
                            {
                                "img" : "www.FantasyimglinkMainstream3.com",
                                "name" : "FantasyMainstreamname3",
                                "description" : "this Fantasy is Mainstream name 3"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
    ]
    }]
```

Thanks for your time, information and insight! please understand I am new to PHP, mysql and JavaScript but not google/stackoverflow I have googled and searched and tried to do this myself but it's just not working..

Just to be clear I want to know how to covert a mySQL database to a json array that I can make requests to from a html + js mobile app.

To confirm how the database was set up:

[image]

Comment: Fetch the data using mysql queries and convert result set into json using json_encode($result);

Comment: Consider providing a simpler, but more representative data set (ideally as a set of DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle) together with both the desired SQL output AND the subsequent json string.

Comment: Mihir Bhatt just exactly what did this comment add? I'm not being rude but I know i have to do this.. isn't that what i said above, in some sense? what i am asking for is how to make it work with the code i have, i even mentioned `json_encode();`  above too, can you please provide some code ? thanks

Comment: basic code = mysqli to json                                                                                                                   `<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','user','pass','database');
    $myArray = array();
    if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tablename")) {
        $tempArray = array();
        while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
                $tempArray = $row;
                array_push($myArray, $tempArray);
            }
        echo "<script>".json_encode($myArray)."</script>";
    }

    $result->close();
    $mysqli->close();

?>`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to put answers (right or wrong, doesn't matter, the vote will determine it) into the answer section. Because it is easier to read

Anyway, try this. This is using PDO (an alternative to mysqli)

1. Connect to database and do a SELECT you can make it as complicated as you want with INNER JOINS, LEFT JOINS, UNIONS, etc

   ```
   $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
   $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM anime"); 
   $stmt->execute();

   // set the resulting array to associative
   $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   ```
2. Then you want to convert it to JSON, via `json_encode` which you already know

   ```
   $output = json_encode($result)
   ```
3. You want to output it (as a JSON). You can use `echo` and don't forget to set the header to be JSON

   ```
   header('Content-Type: application/json');
   echo (output);
   ```

Note that this PHP returns you the JSON, and not injecting it into javascript as what @user1871802 suggested