# mySQL to JSON Object only returns first row

Tags: php, mysql, json

these lines of code :

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM parcours";
$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$result = array();

while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){

 $result[] = $res;
}
echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
```

returns me only the first row of my DB request.

How can I get all of it ?

Comment: Nothing looks obviously wrong with this.  You're sure parcours has more than 1 row in it?  after your while loop var_dump($result) has more than 1 item?

Comment: Yes it has ....

Comment: var_dump($result) has all your rows returned?

Comment: var_dump($result) returned me 2 rows (which is the number of rows)

Comment: Can you copy the output of your echo into your question.  It doesn't look like anything is wrong so far.

Comment: [How to build a JSON array from mysql database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281963/how-to-build-a-json-array-from-mysql-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` :

```
while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){

 $result[] = $res;
}
```

and then :

```
echo json_encode(array($result));
```